# Jscrollpane initialize at the bottom

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using the [jscrollpane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for a custom scrollbar. What i cant accomplish is to initialize at the bottom i.e whenever that window is loaded it should be auto scrolled to the bottom. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the javascript you have written so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you might have multiple `jScrollPane` elements in your website you need to iterate through all of them and call `scrollToBottom` to move the scroll bar to the bottom:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().each(function(){
    $(this).data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
});
```

But of course if you want to move the scroll bar to the bottom of one specific jScrollPane instance `#myJScrollPane` use this:

```
$('#scroll-pane-1').jScrollPane().data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
```

**Example:**

I updated the demo created by @scessor. [Click here to see it.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zQbQ/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly well when i do this on firebug console. But where can i place this code. I tried to put in document.ready and window.load but it didnt work. Any idea ??

Comment: Where did you put your original `.jScrollPane()` function call? Why didn't it work inside `document.ready`? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: I updated the example code created by @scessor. If you open the source of the JSFiddle demo you can see that the script is put inside window load: `$(window).load(function(){
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().each(function(){
    $(this).data('jsp').scrollToBottom();
});` And it works.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTo method should work for this.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to.html

```
var api = pane.data('jsp');
api.scrollTo(0, y);
```

Where y is the height of your area that scrolls.  If this varies, or you don't know it, use a very high value that you are not likely to ever reach and it will scroll to the bottom.